# A question about constant solutions in a Logistic differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y'(x) = y(x) - y^2(x) ~(x > 0)$ and $y(0) > 0$.

Then $y'(x) = y(x)(1-y(x))$. Thus, if $y(0) = 1$ then $y'(0) = 0$.

I know that $y (x ) \equiv 1$ is a solution if $y(0) = 1$.

However, I am not certain that $y(x) \equiv 1$ is the only solution if $y(0) =1$.

How can we prove that $y(x) \equiv 1$ is the only solution if  $y (0) = 1$?

Comment: This follows from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard–Lindelöf_theorem. Uniqueness guarantees this.

Comment: The solution of this separable ODE is :$\quad y(x)=\frac{1}{1+c\:e^{-x}}\quad$ The condition $y(0)=1$ implies a unique value of $c=0$ . Thus the solution $y(x)=1$ is unique.